# Julia undefined import from parallel folder

Tags: import, julia, include, using

I am unable to import a module and use it. The loaded file is declared as undefined. I am calling a function in foo from bar. What is the error?

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: foo not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] callFoo()
   @ Main.bar filepath
\pkg2\bar.jl:6
 [2] top-level scope
   @ filepath\main.jl:4
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
root
   main.jl
   pkg1
       foo.jl
   pkg2
       bar.jl
```

main.jl

```
include("./pkg2/bar.jl")

bar.callFoo()
```

foo.jl

```
module foo

function mul2(val::Int)
    return val*2
end

end
```

bar.jl

```
include("../pkg1/foo.jl")

module bar

function callFoo()
    val1 = foo.mul2(2)
    println(val1)
end

end
```

Comment: I was able to resolve the error by adding "Main." to the function call ```val1 = Main.foo.mul2(2)```. I don't know why this solves it, and this appears to be a bad fix. Any insight as to why this works and alternatives?

Comment: `foo` module is defined in global scope (i.e. Main) and is therefore not available in `bar` module scope. With the `Main.` prefix you are able to access `foo`. Otherwise, you could `import` / `using` the `foo` module from Main to `bar` and then use `foo.mul2`. Each module has its namespace. The relevant link I guess is: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/

Answer (score 0):

In Julia, source code organization and modules are independent. `include` has no bearing on module structure. It is the same as copy and pasting the contents of the `include`d file. ([more info](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/#Definitions))

Because of this, the code in your question is semantically equivalent to

```
module foo

function mul2(val::Int)
    return val*2
end

end 

module bar

function callFoo()
    val1 = foo.mul2(2)
    println(val1)
end

end

bar.callFoo()
```

On to the problem: every module has its own global namespace. This means that, while `foo` is defined in the `Main` namespace, it is not defined in the `bar` namespace. To use the module `foo` from within `bar`, you should load the module `foo` with `using` or `import`, like this:

```
module foo

function mul2(val::Int)
    return val*2
end

end 

module bar

using ..foo

function callFoo()
    val1 = foo.mul2(2)
    println(val1)
end

end

bar.callFoo()
```

You can split this fixed code up into as many files as you would like with `include` statements.